# Fetching data with the endpoint from AWS using React js

Tags: reactjs

I am using axios to fetch data from aws.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
function Employee() {
   const[data, setData] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {
     axios.get('123.56.234.123:8080/employees?num=1')
     .then(response => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
   },[]);
   return data;
}
```

From this code, I got the error message saying

Get http://localhost:8080/123.56.234.123:8080/employees?num=1 431(Request Header Fields Too Large).

I believe the cause is from the wrong url I am getting.

In this case, how can I fetch data from the endpoint?

PS) My node version: 14.XX

Thank you.

Comment: Have you set the `baseURL` to `http://localhost:8080`? Why is it being prepended to your url?

Comment: Seems like it's just using that IP as a relative URL. I would try prepending `http://` or `https://` to `123.56.234.123...` and giving it a try.

Comment: @codemonkey yes it works! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set a PROXY. You have currently set the axios `baseURL` to be localhost:8080. That is why the `get` url is getting prepended to `baseUrl`.

The error `431(Request Header Fields Too Large)` occurs because the Referrer url is too long.

If you are using `create-react-app`, then please [refer this official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually).

Comment: I put proxy at the bottom of package.json. Also, I just changed the baseURL to 3000. Now I get the error message saying ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://123.56.234.123:8080/employees?num=1 from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```